# How to $and with reactivemongo

Tags: mongodb, scala, reactivemongo

I want to create this query in reactivemongo

```
db.ingresos.find({$and: [ {fechaIngreso:{$gt:new Date ("03/06/2014")}}, {fechaIngreso:{$lt:new Date("03/25/2014")}}    ]})
```

but it doesn't work. 
My code:

```
val query = BSONDocument("$and" -> BSONDocument(
    "fechaIngreso" -> BSONDocument(
      "$gte" -> BSONDateTime(fechaInicio.getTime),
      "$lte" -> BSONDateTime(fechaFin.getTime)
    )
  ))
  collection.find(query).sort(BSONDocument("fechaIngreso" -> 1)).cursor[Ingreso].collect[List](20)
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for answer my own question, I actually found the solution.

Here's my code

```
val query = BSONDocument(
    "fechaIngreso" -> BSONDocument(
      "$gte" -> BSONDateTime(fechaInicio.getTime),
      "$lte" -> BSONDateTime(fechaFin.getTime)
    )
  )
  collection.find(query).sort(BSONDocument("fechaIngreso" -> 1)).cursor[Ingreso].collect[List](20)
```

Hope it helps somebody!

Comment: Could you tell me, How do I proceed for the $or ?